# Adding two curves, one of type = 'l' the other of type = 'h' in R?

Tags: r, function, plot, distribution

I was wondering if by any kind of re-scaling of one of the following functions (i.e., multiplying or dividing one function by a constant) it might be possible to *add (i.e., put on top of) This curve:*

```
curve(dbinom(x, 100, .55), 0, 100, ty = "h")
```

*To This curve:*

```
curve(dbinom(55, 100, x))
```

**P.S.** Note that I want for the x axis to range from `0` to `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rescaling,  yes. I think this is what you want.

```
curve(dbinom(x, 100, .55), 0, 100, ty = "h") 
lines(seq(0,100,0.5), dbinom(55, 100, seq(0,100,0.5)/100))
```

[image: Binomial distribution]

Alternatively, you can get the same result using

```
curve(dbinom(x, 100, .55), 0, 100, ty = "h") 
curve(dbinom(55, 100, x/100), add=TRUE)
```

Comment: Not at all!   You can reverse them although you will need to specify `xlim =c(0,100)` if you do.